# Simple Script, error: "Syntax error: missing : after property id"

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am a NetSuite Administrator but have not had much programming experience. I am trying to build a simple script that will send an email, before a record is deleted, with information from the record being deleted. I have done research online and think I have a good base here but I'm getting the error: "Syntax error: missing : after property id" when I try to upload my script.

```
function SendJEworkflowAction(){
    nlapiSendEmail(38214, 'druch@apogee.us',
                   'Fulfillment with Journal Entry Deleted',
                   {custbody_bpc_journal_entry}
                  );
    nlapiLogExecution('emailsent', mlapiGetRecordId());
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: `{}` signifies an object which is expected to follow the format of `{key:value}`.  As such `{custbody_bpc_journal_entry}` does not match this syntax.

Comment: `{custbody_bpc_journal_entry}` isn't valid syntax. You either mean `custbody_bpc_journal_entry` or `{<property-name>:custbody_bpc_journal_entry}`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to load the record and stringify it. Make sure you are doing this beforeSubmit. Try this:

```
function SendJEworkflowAction(){
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(),nlapiGetRecordId());
    nlapiSendEmail(38214, 'druch@apogee.us',
                   'Fulfillment with Journal Entry Deleted',
                   JSON.stringify(record)
                  );
    nlapiLogExecution('emailsent', nlapiGetRecordId());
}
```